# How can I change the length of a vector in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust

> Editor's note: This question predates Rust 1.0 and  syntax and methods have changed since then. Some answers account for Rust 1.0.

I have a function which I would like to have modify a vector in place.

```
fn f(v: &mut Vec<int>) {
    v = Vec::from_elem(10 as uint, 0i);
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<int> = Vec::new();
    f(&mut v);
}
```

But this fails to compile.  Specifically, I would like to resize `v` to contain 10 elements of value zero.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you wish to overwrite you need to dereference `v`, since it's a pointer. `*v = Vec::from_elem(10 as uint, 0i);`.

Comment: Note: `10u` is shorthand for `10 as uint`, but actually `10` being untyped means that the compiler will infer it should be a `uint` and "do the right thing". Similarly, since `Vec` is inferred to be `Vec<int>`, just `0` instead of `0i` is sufficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`clear`](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.clear) and [`resize`](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize) methods. (This seems to be the right answer as of Rust 1.0 and 1.5, respectively.)

```
fn f(v: &mut Vec<u32>) {
    // Remove all values in the vector
    v.clear();

    // Fill the vector with 10 zeros
    v.resize(10, 0);
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    f(&mut v);
    assert!(v == [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Editor's note: This answer predates Rust 1.0 and is no longer necessarily accurate. Other answers still contain valuable information.

You're looking for the `grow` method.

```
let mut vec = vec![1i,2,3];
vec.grow(4, &10);
println!("{}", vec);
```

Or a combination of `grow` and `clear`.

You can browse the docs here: http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/vec/struct.Vec.html

Comment: Thanks!  Searching that page for "resize", "length", and "capacity" and scanning through the functions did not help.  I never expected it to be called `grow`!

Comment: There is no longer a `grow` method in the current version of Rust.